# Grouping by 'equal sums'

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I'm trying to take a list of numbers, and put them into >=N groups such that the sums of each groups are approximately (but not necessarily exactly) equal, and 'outliers' can be in a group of their own.

So for a target of 3 groups and an input of something like:

```
[3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 5]
```

The output might be:

```
[[5,1], [4,2], [3,2]]
```

The respective sums of each group being

```
6, 6, 5
```

I think I've got the methodology down, as pseudocode it looks something like this:

```
let target = Ceil(Sum(Series) / NumberOfTargetGroups) //The ideal size of each group

while (count(UnpickedNumbers) > 0)
    let CurrentGroup = new group
    while (sum(CurrentGroup) < target)
        for each Unpicked in sortDesc(UnpickedNumbers)
            if (sum(CurrentGroup) + Unpicked)
                Add Unpicked to current group
                Remove unpicked from available numbers
```

What I can't figure out is how to turn that logic into a `GroupBy(n => ...)` - the reason for wanting to do this being that the list of numbers is actually coming from a property of a series of objects that I want to group in this manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partition is NP-complete problem.
I've preapred snippet:

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TObject>> Algo<TObject>(IEnumerable<TObject> source, int groups,
                                                       Func<TObject, int> intSelector)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }

    source = source.OrderByDescending(intSelector);
    var evaluated = source as IList<TObject> ?? source.ToList();
    if (groups > evaluated.Count())
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid group count.");
    }

    var result = new List<List<TObject>>();
    for (var i = 0; i < groups; i++)
    {
        result.Add(new List<TObject> { evaluated[i] });
    }

    for (var i = groups; i < evaluated.Count(); i++)
    {
        var bestIndex = 0;
        var bestSum = result[bestIndex].Sum(intSelector);
        for (var j = 1; j < result.Count; j++)
        {
            var sum = result[j].Sum(intSelector);
            if (sum < bestSum)
            {
                bestSum = sum;
                bestIndex = j;
            }
        }

        result[bestIndex].Add(evaluated[i]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

It is not efficient (there are many ways to optimize it) and the result is not always optimial. But hope that it will be base for your algorithm (maybe approx. is enough for you - test it!).

EDIT:
I've modified snippet for you - you don't have to use `GroupBy`. Usage:

```
var widgets = new List<Widget>  { W1, W2, etc. };
var result = Algo(widgets, groups: 3, intSelector: widget => widget.Height);
```

Comment: This implements it fine, but what I still can't figure out is how I can use it with GroupBy() so that I can use it on my objects. So say I was grouping my IEnumerable<Widget> by the Widget.Height property in this manner.

Comment: @PhonicUK wha'ts more, you don't have to use `GroupBy` :)

Comment: @L.B well, if OP or other readers won't learn anything - it's their loss :) Important thing is that I've learnt something :)